# How to document undergrad math knowledge?

Tags: soft-question, education

If you did a degree which is low on math (read economics, psychology), but want to proceed to a more mathematically loaded master, how would you document your knowledge?

Are there standarized examinations that are widely recognized?

That would also be a way of discovering how weak one is in math, not only to prove towards others.

Comment: I'm not sure about "standarized", but many (perhaps most?) decent universities have a rather clear low raft undergraduates must fulfill to get into graduate school. I think you should check with your target universities about this. Economics, psychology have generally waaaaaay too low a level in mathematics to be considered, imo, deserving...

Comment: In Germany there are some masters called "business mathematics" which do not require to be a "full" mathematician but to have good working knowledge in economics and business. Also the psychological masters can be more theoretical requiring an advanced level of statistics.

Comment: Because it's really pertinent to the answers you are seeking: what exactly are you considering to be a "more mathematically loaded" degree? Do you have a specific degree in mind? Physics? Engineering? Another?

Comment: The way would be biochemistry > computational biology or bioinformatics. The jump is not bizarre but definitely they expect a higher degree of math than given through the undergrad degree. I'd want to learn the math by myself and could then try to pass an exam to validate my knowledge.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are applying for math graduate school in the US many schools would require the Math subject GRE. See http://www.ets.org/gre/subject/about/content/mathematics for what is covered. It's a multiple choice test but it's pretty challenging (and requires you to work fast).

Comment: I think that would be a good alternative.